# How to customize background color of button using Material UI themes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't figure out from the documentation how to style a button so the background color of that component is purple using Material UI themes. I can get the text color to change to purple with the below. Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import purple from '@material-ui/core/colors/purple';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
          main:purple[500],
      }
    },
  });
export default class Practice extends Component {
render(){
return (
    <div>
       <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
           <Button color="primary">Add theme</Button>
       </ThemeProvider>
</div>
)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const theme = createTheme({
 overrides : {
   MuiButton : {
     root : {
    // apply your style here 
   }
 },
 palette: {
   primary: {
      main:purple[500],
  }
},
```

});

Comment: This works, thank you! What I don't understand is how to use this feature for any component type? Where does the MuiButton part come from?

Comment: the MuiButton is the classname of the components, you can access each component by it's class for example you want to change an item in a list component, you just access the ListItem class then it's root , just like we did with the button

Answer (score 0):

For the currently latest MUI 5 it should be (from the docs):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to change the default for.
        disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
      },
    },
  },
});
```

And then provide your `theme` as usual.

More info: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#default-props